# Swift: Add image to CALayer returns black

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, core-animation, calayer

Very simply, I'm trying to add an image to a CALayer as a watermark on the video. I have done this on projects in the past and it has worked but for some reason it's consistently returning a black image on my current project.

Here is code:

- I've unwrapped 'logo' to ensure it is valid
- I've set the background to green. Currently the frame is filled black (not green), so I assume it is returning the image, but rendering black for some reason.

  ```
    if let logo = options.logoImage {
        let layer = CALayer()
        animationLayer.addSublayer(layer)
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        layer.contents = logo.cgImage
        layer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set your **layer** to the mask property:

```
layer.mask = imageSubLayer // or whatever it is called
```

So it would  look something like this:

```
if let logo = options.logoImage {
      let layer = CALayer()
      animationLayer.addSublayer(layer)
      layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
      layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
      layer.contents = logo.cgImage
      layer.mask = animationLayer
      layer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
  }
```

---

Edit:

**CALayer**`s are very transient and doesn't work properly outside of animations:

I tried to reproduce what you did (I just assumed you created your **animationLayer** the same I did):

```
  var animationLayer: CALayer = {
        let l = CALayer()
        l.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        return l
    }()
```

Comment: The whole CALayer just disappears when I add this.

Comment: Can you share how you create the **animationLayer**

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this. I think the images I was using were corrupt or something. I restarted my app, Xcode, and imported different images and my original code works now. Thanks again